# How to set file access rights using Node.js on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, filesystems, file-permissions

To setup who can access what file, Node.js's `fs` module provides a number of functions, such as [chown](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chown_path_uid_gid_callback).

While this works pretty well on macOS and Linux, it is rather a workaround than a solution on Windows, as Windows does not support such fine-granular permissions on the file system level. However, I know that using the properties dialog in Windows Explorer you can assign permissions to users and groups.

How can I adjust this using Node.js? Apparently, `chown` and co. do not perform this task, do they?

PS: Of course I can run `icacls` using a shell command, but I thought that there *might* be a better way. Is there?